# How to fetch data with if function from 1 table to another table

Tags: mysql, database, select, data-retrieval

#### table_Pricing

```
ProductType = Lookup from table ProductCatalog.ProductDutyType (dropdown combo)
```

Duty= ?

#### table_ProductCatalog

Columns-

```
ProductDutyType-   Custom
Pens-               15
Bags-                5
Organizers-         10
Dresses-             3
```

What i need is when I select in the product type dropdown of table_Pricing, then the duty column should fetch the value from custom column of table_ProductCatalog, depending on the selected product type.

If i select Product type  in table Pricing, the Duty column should compare the 2 tables and display the value in the custom colum for Bags, that is 5.

Hope someone understand me. Please help, Newbee here.

Comment: Mysql doesn't have dropdowns. Is your question about how to do this in HTML/Javascript/AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT custom 
FROM table_ProductCatalog
WHERE ProductDutyType = 'Bags';
```